# Process elements at the same index of two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can do with `Array#map`:

```
let arr_1 = [6, 3, 2,10];
let arr_2 = [7, 5, 5,10];
const newArr= arr_1.map(function(x, index){ 
  return arr_2[index] + x 
 });

output: [13, 8, 7, 20];
```

But how can I do it with a `for` loop?

Comment: If they are both the same sized list you could loop from i =0; to i < arr_1.length and add the values and either populate a new array or overwrite one of your arrays. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop as below:

```
let arr_1 = [6, 3, 2, 10];
let arr_2 = [7, 5, 5, 10];
let output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr_1.length; i++) {
  output.push(arr_1[i] + arr_2[i]);
}

console.log(output);
output: [ 13, 8, 7, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [];

for (let i = 0 ;i < Math.min(arr_1.length,arr_2.length) ; i++) {
    arr.push(arr_1[i] + arr_2[i]);
}
```

Note that if they have different sized the smaller size one will be considered and remaining items will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a function to elements at the same index is usually a job for a `zipWith` function:

```js
const zipWith = f => (xs, ys) => {
  const len = Math.min(xs.length, ys.length);
  const ret = [];
  for (let i=0; i<len; i+=1) ret.push(f(xs[i], ys[i]));
  return ret;
};
```

Since *what you do* is passed as a function `f` then you can do many things:

```js
const out = inp => console.log(JSON.stringify(inp))

const add = zipWith((a, b) => a + b);
const mult = zipWith((a, b) => a * b);
const pair = zipWith((a, b) => [a, b]);

out(add([6, 3, 2,10], [7, 5, 5,10]));
out(mult([6, 3, 2,10], [7, 5, 5,10]));
out(pair([6, 3, 2,10], [7, 5, 5,10]));
```

```html
<script>
const zipWith = f => (xs, ys) => {
  const len = Math.min(xs.length, ys.length);
  const ret = [];
  for (let i=0; i<len; i+=1) ret.push(f(xs[i], ys[i]));
  return ret;
}
</script>
```